# Trying to use os.path.exists via variables but getting an error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file called `serial.dll`. The content of this file is another file's name:

```
a-2ED1-7156.dll
```

I also have 1 file called `a-2ED1-7156.dll` in the same directory.

When I try to check if the file exists by reading its name from `serial.dll`:

```py
f = open('serial.dll', 'r')

serials = f.read()

if os.path.exists(serials):
    print("ok")
else:
    print("no")
```

Always results "no".

but:

```py
file = 'a-2ED1-7156.dll'

if os.path.exists(file):
    print("ok")
else:    
    print("no")
```

Always gives the correct result.

How can I check if the file `a-2ED1-7156.dll` exists by reading it from the `serial.dll` file?

```
Update Try: 

f = open('serial.dll', 'r')
lines = f.readline()
for line in lines:
    if os.path.exists(line):
        print('ok')
    else:
        print("no")

results error:
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
ok
no
no
no
no
```

Comment: In the first code you ask if the **content** of "serial.dll" is an existing path.

Comment: What does `print(serials)` give you…?

Comment: @MichaelButscher this is exactly what he is trying to do...

Comment: @Tomerikoo This was hard to understand in the original question and it is, well, uncommon to use a DLL-file to store a filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that lines in a file might end with the new-line character. File names usually don't have that character... For example, right now you're checking if the file `a-2ED1-7156.dll\n` exists - which is not. You simply need to [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) the lines before checking them as files:

```py
f = open('serial.dll')

for line in f:
    filename = line.strip()
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        print(f"{filename} exists")
    else:
        print(f"{filename} doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 1):

Supossing each file is in a separate line, you coud use

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if os.path.exists(line):
        print('ok')
```

Or print only if all files exist, depending on what you want exactly.

Comment: Report error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'